# Assign a key number to a key in the object by incrementing count

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects . I need to convert the value of the 'key' by incrementing count .

lets say I have an array

```
const arr1=[{key:'a', val:1},{key:'b',val:2}]
```

I want to give an incrementing key value to each  key

I have tried the below code but couldn't override the count value

```
   let count = 0;
   const arr1=[{key:'a', val:1},{key:'b',val:2}]
   arr1.map(el => el.key=count+1);
   console.log(arr1)
```

Expected Result : 
   `[ { key: 1, val: 1 }, { key: 2, val: 2 } ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `++` to update `count` while getting the new value. Also, you need to return the modified `el` from `map`, and make sure you assign the return value otherwise it'll be garbage-collected - `map` returns a new array.

```js
let count = 0;

const arr1 = [{key:'a',val:1},{key:'b',val:2}];

const res = arr1.map(({ val }) => ({ key: ++count, val }));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop through the array and update the key based on the index

```js
const array = [ { key: 1, val: 1 }, { key: 2, val: 2 } ]
array.forEach((o, i) => o.key = i+1)
console.log(array)
```

If you want a new array you could use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like this:

```js
const array = [ { key: 1, val: 1 }, { key: 2, val: 2 } ],
      newArray = array.map((o, i) => ({ ...o, key: i+1}));

console.log(newArray)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because it looks like you want to perform side-effects rather than create a new array, use `forEach` instead of `.map`. You also need to actually increment the `count` variable on each iteration:

```js
let count = 0;
const arr1=[{key:'a', val:1},{key:'b',val:2}]

arr1.forEach(el => {
  count++;
  el.key = count;
});
console.log(arr1)
```